# Is it possible to display values where the display ends instead of on top of the points with chartjs?

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am trying to add the value of the line chart on top of the grid lines instead of the point itself.

I have managed to add the value on top of the bar using the below code:

```
    options: {
        "animation": {
            "duration": 1,
                        "onComplete": function () {
                            var chartInstance = this.chart,
                                ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

                            ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                            ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                            this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                                var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                                meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                                    var data = dataset.data[index];                            
                                    ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                                });
                            });
                        }
        },
}
```

What I want is to display the value at the end of the red gridlines instead of the red box shown in the following pen: https://codepen.io/paufar/pen/VOpZGQ

Is it possible to change the value position?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MdxaYp)?

If you store your data outside the chart itself you can then access it from the ticks callback of a second x axis:

```
var data = [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 8];

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['SUN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Tickets Sold',
      data: data,
      backgroundColor: gradient
    }]
    ...
  },
  options: {
    ...
    xAxes:  [{
      position: 'top',
      ticks: {
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          return data[index];
        }
      }
    }, {
      ...
    }],
    ...
  },
});
```

Comment: Actually managed to do it using this: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/ Thanks @Danny!